# First time drag and drop issue of position in bootstrap modal for ui sortable

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-sortable

I am facing a drag and drop issue for an event executing for the first time. That issue is related to the position of the image when I drag and drop it to another place for the first time.

The issue is shown below.
[image]

Here is the code :

```
$(document).on("click", ".make_pdf", function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('url');        
    $('.modal-body').html('Loading...');
    $('.modal-body').load(url,function(result){
        $('#make-pdf').modal({show:true});
        $( this ).children('.user-settings').children('.pdf-list').children('#sortable').sortable();
        $( this ).children('.user-settings').children('.pdf-list').children('#sortable').disableSelection();
    });
});
```

For more information. This drag and drop works properly without the modal so please can you any one help to solve this with the bootstrap modal?

Here js fiddle link.
https://jsfiddle.net/zrLv0ogj/11/
Please increase the height and width of the output window in jsfiddle.

Jsfiddle Image link.
http://prntscr.com/kp1axw

Comment: Please create a simple fiddle of your problem please, we can't help without seeing any code...

Comment: Okay I have added that https://jsfiddle.net/bhavin1/zrLv0ogj/ please check this link and for making issue you have to increase the height and width of the output window in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$(document)
  .on('mouseup', function() {
    $('.modal').css('overflow', '');
  })
  .on('mousedown', '.ui-sortable-handle', function() {
    $('.modal').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, it's a bug of jquery who append if you use a "overflow:auto" on a parents div of the sortable. When you load the page and scroll down, if you drag an item, the first time jquery do a wrong calculation of the position "top" of the helper element.

So for me this solution works well, I just refresh the position of the sortable only on the first drag :

```js
var firstDrag= true;
$("ul").sortable(
{
  start: function(e,ui)
  {
    // Refresh position only for first drag
    if(firstDrag)
    {
      $(this).sortable("refreshPositions");
      firstDrag= false;
    }
});
```